# GroupBy then sum in separate expressions in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

Usually when we do `GroupBy` and `Sum` in Entity Framework, we have something like this:

```
var query = from q in db
            group q by q.Gender into g
            select new
                {
                  name = g.Key,
                  value = g.Sum(a => a.saving_amount)
                };
```

If I want to separate the above queries and build `GroupBy` and select to `Sum` step by step, I have:

```
var q1 = from q in db
         group q by q.Gender

var q2 = q1.Select (g=> new{
    name = g.Key
    value = g.Sum(a => a.saving_amount)
});
```

However if I do this, I get an error message

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'saving_amount' and no accessible extension method 'saving amount'...

To make sure I do have the 'saving_amount' I output my result as so

```
var q1 = from q in db
         group q by pc.Gender

var q2 = q1.Select (g=> new{
    name = g.Key
    value = g.ToList()
});
```

and confirmed my 'saving_amount' is a property in the list of objects. (below is a sample output through an API using Postman)

> [{"name":"Female","value":[{"id":"xxxxxxxx","version":"R","issue_date":"2021-01-26T00:00:00","saving_amount":100000.0000,...

My question is how can I sum the 'saving_amount' under the separated query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've resolved it by using below instead

```
var q1 = from q in db
         group q by q.Gender

var q2 = q1.Select (g=> new{
    name = g.Key
    value = g.Select(a => a.saving_amount).Sum()
});
```

Comment: strange, that code produces the same IL as the code that wasn't working, doesn't it?

Comment: IL would be different for sure. @KY that error message was during compilation or at runtime? if at runtime I think this is a candidate for bug-report to the ef-core team on github.

Comment: @RufusL pardon me, what does IL stands for? New to coding here.

Comment: @BogdanMart The error occur at compilation, appearing as a red line highlighting my the part saying " a=>a.saving_amount" in my Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: It's the intermediate language that 's produced by the compiler for all .NET framework languages (such as c#, Visual Basic .NET, F#, etc).  You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/managed-code)

Comment: @BogdanMart There should be no functional difference between this answer and the code in the question (i.e. the difference between `value = g.Select(a => a.saving_amount).Sum()` and `value = g.Sum(a => a.saving_amount)`). The IL for `Select(condition).Sum()` and `Sum(condition)` should be identical. For example, take a look at [this code sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y5ndqm) and click the "Tidy Up -> View IL" button, then navigate to the bottom and compare the IL for `'<Main>b__1'` to the IL for `'<Main>b__2`. I don't see any reason why the answer code works if the question code doesn't.